# How to get tab space in 'markdown' cell of Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am writing descriptive ipynb file and need to give output in markdown with space, but unable to add tab space for printing structured data.

Answer (score 52):

1. Type "nbsp" to add a single space.
2. Type "ensp" to add 2 spaces.
3. Type "emsp" to add 4 spaces.
4. Use the non-breaking space (nbsp) 4 times to insert a tab.

eg.
`&emsp;This is an example.`

Answer (score 13):

I just had this problem and resorted to the following:

This is text with `$\;\;\;\;\;\;$` some space inserted.

Comment: This is weird. This basically parses LaTeX so as to reserve an SVG space for a maths expression that will consist of non-printable characters. But hey, it works

Answer (score 7):

Markdown is used primarily to generate HTML, and HTML collapses white spaces by default. Use `"&nbsp;"` instead of space characters.

Type `"&nbsp"` to add a single space.
Type `"&ensp"` to add 2 spaces.
Type `"&emsp"` to add 4 spaces.

Comment: 's solution needs semicolons, for example &emsp;

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question then I don't think this has anything to do with Jupyter cells. For example, are you able to type a tab key into a Stackoverflow question box? Most browsers do not allow tab keys in most dialogs on most websites -- instead, tab switches to the next area.

Some options:

1. cut a tab from a text application, paste into a Jupyter cell. (works)
2. try using a browser-specific extension, like [TabMeansTab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-means-tab/pekbppdfbdcbabghglhpckdfemdfaech?hl=en) for Chrome or [Tabinta](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tabinta/) for Firefox.

See also further discussions of typing tab keys in browsers *in general* on SuperUser:

- https://superuser.com/questions/67934/typing-the-tab-character-in-browser-text-boxes
- https://superuser.com/questions/522627/how-to-use-tab-key-to-indent-within-a-textfield-instead-of-jumping-to-next-elem

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to write some descriptive fancy script in my Jupyter Notebook Markdown cell but there is no answer that could help me to make it copy-pastable in my Jupyter Notebook Code cell when I run it. For example:

```
`def my_fancy_code():`    
&emsp;<s>`n = 'some name that has a special effect'`</s>  
&ensp;&ensp;<s>`n = 'some name that has a special effect'`</s>  
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<s>`n = 'some name that has a special effect'`</s>  
$\;\;\;\;\;\;$<s>`n = 'some name that has a special effect'`</s>
```

gives me some fancy output, but after I paste it in mu Jupyter Notebook Code cell I get something like this:

```
def my_fancy_code():
 n = 'some name that has a special effect'
  n = 'some name that has a special effect'
    n = 'some name that has a special effect'
n = 'some name that has a special effect'
```

Actualy, `&nbsp;`, `&ensp;`, `&mnsp;` are substitutes for SPACE character that can't   used in Python code in order to replace TABs. Also `$\;\;\;\;\;\;$` won't make any copyable spaces at all. The best solution I found is to use this way:

```
<code>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</code>
```

Or you can simply use just `<code>    </code>` with 4 spaces inside.
It makes a perfect gap of 4 spaces length which can be copied in Python scripts instead of TAB characters.